# DVB adapter under kernel 3.13.0-35 and above

Tags: server, kernel, mythtv, dvb

I have a Ubuntu 14.04.1 server with a MythTV backend server and a Digital Devices DVB adapter. The server has been working fine, but if I upgrade the kernel from 3.13.0-34 to 3.13.0-35/3.13.0-36 my DVB adapter is no longer detected properly. Under kernel 3.13.0-34 I have these two "catalogs" under /dev:

```
/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0
/dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0
```

Under 3.13.0-35 and 3.13.0-36 the entire dvb catalog is missing.

lspci gives me the same result under all three kernel versions:

```
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Digital Devices GmbH Octopus DVB Adapter
```

Under 3.13.0-34 I'm perfectly capable of recording anything I want, but when I boot with 3.13.0-35 or 3.13.0-36 my mythbackend.log shows this:

```
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: W CoreContext recorders/dvbchannel.cpp:229 (Open) DVBChan[1](/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0): Opening DVB frontend device failed.#012#011#011#011eno: No such file or directory (2)
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext recorders/dvbchannel.cpp:234 (Open) DVBChan[1](/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0): Failed to open DVB frontend device due to fatal error or too many attempts.
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext recorders/channelbase.cpp:1232 (CreateChannel) ChannelBase: CreateChannel() Error: Failed to open device /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext main_helpers.cpp:199 (setupTVs) Problem with capture cardsCard 1failed init
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: W CoreContext recorders/dvbchannel.cpp:229 (Open) DVBChan[2](/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0): Opening DVB frontend device failed.#012#011#011#011eno: No such file or directory (2)
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext recorders/dvbchannel.cpp:234 (Open) DVBChan[2](/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0): Failed to open DVB frontend device due to fatal error or too many attempts.
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext recorders/channelbase.cpp:1232 (CreateChannel) ChannelBase: CreateChannel() Error: Failed to open device /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext main_helpers.cpp:199 (setupTVs) Problem with capture cardsCard 2failed init
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: W CoreContext recorders/dvbchannel.cpp:229 (Open) DVBChan[3](/dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0): Opening DVB frontend device failed.#012#011#011#011eno: No such file or directory (2)
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext recorders/dvbchannel.cpp:234 (Open) DVBChan[3](/dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0): Failed to open DVB frontend device due to fatal error or too many attempts.
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext recorders/channelbase.cpp:1232 (CreateChannel) ChannelBase: CreateChannel() Error: Failed to open device /dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext main_helpers.cpp:199 (setupTVs) Problem with capture cardsCard 3failed init
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: W CoreContext recorders/dvbchannel.cpp:229 (Open) DVBChan[4](/dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0): Opening DVB frontend device failed.#012#011#011#011eno: No such file or directory (2)
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext recorders/dvbchannel.cpp:234 (Open) DVBChan[4](/dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0): Failed to open DVB frontend device due to fatal error or too many attempts.
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext recorders/channelbase.cpp:1232 (CreateChannel) ChannelBase: CreateChannel() Error: Failed to open device /dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0
Sep 24 20:43:18 obelix mythbackend: mythbackend[1761]: E CoreContext main_helpers.cpp:199 (setupTVs) Problem with capture cardsCard 4failed init
```

I don't remember seeing any errors when I upgraded to 3.13.0-35 or 3.13.0-36. Can anybody here help me getting my DVB adapter working again under 3.13.0-35 or 3.13.0-36?

I'm currently booting the server using the 3.13.0-34 kernel, but I would prefer to use the latest kernel available at any given moment in time.

When I installed the server, I used dddvb-dkms to get the drivers for the DVB adapter. Could it be an error in dddvb-dkms 0.9.14.1yavdr1 that's causing the problems under the two newest kernels?

Comment: I tried uninstalling dddvb-dkms, upgrade the kernel to 3.13.0_44 and then reinstall dddvb-dkms. This seems to have solved my problem.